# $f:P_{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, polynomials, solution-verification

Let $P_{n}$ denote the set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ with integer coefficients. I want to show that $f:P_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ given by $f(a_{0}z^{n} + a_{1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_{n-1}z + a_{n}) = (a_{0},a_{1}, \dots , a_{n})$ is bijective.

Attempt:

(Injective): We need to show if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. Suppose $f(a_{0}z^{n} + a_{1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_{n})=f(b_{0}z^{n} + b_{1}z^{n-1} + \dots + b_{n})$. Then, $(a_{0},a_{1}, \dots , a_{n}) = (b_{0}, b_{1}, \dots , b_{n})$. Comparing coefficients, injectivity follows.

(Surjective): We need to show for all $y \in \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ there exists an $x \in P_{n}$ such that $f(x)=y$. Let $y \in \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. Then $y$ is of the form $(y_{0},y_{1}, \dots , y_{n})$. Then take the polynomial $y_{0}z^{n} + y_{1}z^{n-1} + \dots + y_{n}$, applying $f$ to this polynomial we get $ f(y_{0}z^{n} + y_{1}z^{n-1} + \dots + y_{n}) = (y_{0}, y_{1}, \dots , y_{n})$.

Since $f$ is both injective and surjective, $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Looks all correct to me.